# Содержимое слайдера вылезло из контейнера

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Помогите пожалуйста со слайдером! В  javascript плохо разбираюсь (

Нашла подходящее мне решение, но никак не могу настроить под себя. Нашла [здесь](http://lantana-studio.ru/howto/simpleslider/).

У меня содержимое слайдера вылезло из контейнера, фото прикреплю

```js
/* Индекс слайда по умолчанию */
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

/* Функция увеличивает индекс на 1, показывает следующй слайд*/
function plusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

/* Функция уменьшяет индекс на 1, показывает предыдущий слайд*/
function minusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);  
}

/* Устанавливает текущий слайд */
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

/* Основная функция слайдера */
function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__block");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dots_item");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
}
```

```css
.slider {
 position: relative;
}
.slider__block {
 width: 840px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 8px -5px #000;
}
.slider__img {
 margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.slider__block_text {
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.slider__block_fio {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.067rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-900';
 margin-right: 33px;
 margin-left: -64px;
}
.slider__block_vk {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-900';
 margin-right: 140px;
 color: #23aae2;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #cce6f6;
}
.slider__block_place {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-100';
 color: #3eb0e4;
}
.slider__block_text-description {
 font-size: 0.933rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-100Italic';
 color: #363636;
}
/* Кнопки вперед и назад */
.slider .prev, .slider .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.slider .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* При наведении на кнопки добавляем фон кнопок */
.slider .prev:hover,
.slider .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Кружочки */
.slider-dots {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.slider-dots_item{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.slider-dots_item:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
/* Анимация слайдов */
.slider .slider__block {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         1Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         2Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         3Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="minusSlide()">◀</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide()">▶</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-dots">
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
```

[image: Вот что получается]

[image: Вот что сейчас, нужно связать слайдер с кружочками внизу]

Comment: Ребята, со слайдером вроде разобралась, но теперь кружочки внизу пропадают. Консоль выдает ошибку в последней строке JS кода.

Comment: Ошибку то покажите.

Comment: Сейчас со слайдером все ок, все на месте, как надо. Но остался последний нюанс... Мне нужно чтобы нижние кружочки были связаны со слайдером, я так понимаю за это отвечает последняя строка JS кода??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/* Индекс слайда по умолчанию */
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

/* Функция увеличивает индекс на 1, показывает следующй слайд*/
function plusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex += 1);
}

/* Функция уменьшяет индекс на 1, показывает предыдущий слайд*/
function minusSlide() {
    showSlides(slideIndex -= 1);  
}

/* Устанавливает текущий слайд */
function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

/* Основная функция слайдера */
function showSlides(n) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider__block");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-dots_item");
    if (n > slides.length) {
      slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", " ");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
/* необходимо добавить пробел сюда - " active" */
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.slider {
 position: relative;
}
.slider__block {
 width: 840px;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 8px -5px #000;
}
.slider__img {
 margin: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.slider__block_text {
 margin-top: 15px;
}
.slider__block_fio {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 1.067rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-900';
 margin-right: 33px;
 margin-left: -64px;
}
.slider__block_vk {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-900';
 margin-right: 140px;
 color: #23aae2;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #cce6f6;
}
.slider__block_place {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-100';
 color: #3eb0e4;
}
.slider__block_text-description {
 font-size: 0.933rem;
 font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-100Italic';
 color: #363636;
}
/* Кнопки вперед и назад */
.slider .prev, .slider .next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.slider .next {
    right: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
/* При наведении на кнопки добавляем фон кнопок */
.slider .prev:hover,
.slider .next:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
/* Кружочки */
.slider-dots {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.slider-dots_item{
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}
.active,
.slider-dots_item:hover {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
/* Анимация слайдов */
.slider .slider__block {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {
        opacity: .4
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         1Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         2Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider__block d-flex__row">
      <div class="">
       <img src="img/otziv-img.png" alt="Фото" class="slider__img">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__block_text">
       <div class="slider__block_text-row d-flex__widthHeight-center">
        <p class="slider__block_fio">
         3Диана Апасова
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_vk">
         vk.com/apasova
        </p>
        <p class="slider__block_place">
         Москва → София
        </p>
       </div>
       <div class="slider__block_text-description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="prev" onclick="minusSlide()">◀</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlide()">▶</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-dots">
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
      <span class="slider-dots_item" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Прокомментируйте пожалуйста, что вы изменили и почему

Comment: В данном коде была допущена ошибка. 
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active"; - в этой строчке необходимо добавить пробел перед "active" т.к. происходила склейка классов.

Comment: Внесите это в ответ, пожалуйста, кнопка "править". Комментарий потом можно удалить.